# Django: use a Foreignkey relationship for custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I am writing a webapp where I want to have a general `Person` table to uniquely identify any person interacting with the website, e.g. to be able to comply to GDPR requests.

Some `Person`s will also be `User`s in the authentication sense.
I'd like to use `Person.email` for the username.

However, I cannot manage to make authentication / admin interface work.

Simplified models:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    USERNAME_FIELD = ...# what to put here?
```

I found a very old Django issue that seems related:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21832

Any idea, how to make this work with a foreign key to hold the basic user information?

Answer (score 0):

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

Here you go for correct way of achieving this

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = ['email']  # It's mean you can login with your email

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Note: If you use `AbstractBaseUser` models, then you have to write custom model manager.

To avoid writing custom models manager, you should use `AbstractUser`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
      pass
      # here all the required fields like email, name etc item
```

You can create `Person` record for the user when a user records creating using django signal:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

Comment: No each person is forced to have a user, right? And the email field is duplicated at both `Person` and `Email`. That's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the answer. 

You populate the `Person` fields as soon as a `User` table populated using django `signal`